# How can i display a nested list in a multiple select or with checkboxes in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can i display a nested list in a multiple select or with checkboxes in Rails?

My table looks like this:

```
|  id  |  parent_id   |   name   |   lft   |   rgt   |
```

Thanks...

Comment: This problem is related to javascript/jquery. You can easily find jquery plugins for your requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this link

http://code.google.com/p/checkboxtree/

For demo http://checkboxtree.googlecode.com/svn/tags/checkboxtree-0.4.3/index.html